# VS2015 JavaScript intelliSense does not work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I just do not know how to adjust VS2015 JavaScript intelliSense.
I have durandal project and use some standard libraries, and syncfusion controls.
I tried with vs2015 update1, update2 and update3 and none of them work.

In root folder of my project I add Scripts/_references.js. 
Since I am using require I add only those two lines of code in _references.js:

```
/// <autosync enabled="false" />
/// <reference path="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="../app/main.js" start-page="../index.html" />
```

I also tried to turn on auto sync and to update all files in _references.js, it did not help.
My college work on the same project and intelliSense work perfect in his VS2015.

When I open JavaScript Output tab, I see:

```
Referenced file '../../durandal/system.js' not found.
Referenced file '../../web/ej.togglebutton.js' not found.
Referenced file '../../knockout.js' not found.
```

Seem it work to my college, file structure is ok, I just do not know what to do ?

Comment: Do you test in VS2015 Update 1, Update 2 and Update 3 on the same version by installing the Update one by one? Please run your VS in safe mode to check whether this issue caused by third part VS packages. And please try reset your VS settings to check whether there has some settings cause this issue.

Comment: I tried different versions on different computers, but now I have Update 3 on all machines. I tries VS from safe mode (I do not have any special 3rd party library), also tried with reset settings to general, I also do not have any special settings and it does not work.

Comment: Please share a sample project here and share the detailed steps about how do you operate the js files, which can help us reproduce this issue. In addition, since this project works on your college's machine, I suggest you compare your machine and VS environment with your college's machine, such as installed programs on machine, VS version, windows version and so on, whether there has any differences?

Comment: I compared version of VS and we have completely the same version , also both have win 10. Packages in VS are a bit different but difference is in some, as far as I know, unimportant packages (some text editors and so on...), bot of as have Web Essential Pack package. I will try to provide some sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project/solution is on another drive? I mean on a different drive of the VS installation. This problem has happened to me because my VS installation is on Drive "C", and my solution on Drive "D". In the JavaScript Language Service Output windows, I saw "Referenced file '../../../../project/scripts/main.js' not found.". When I move the project to the C Drive, everything is working as expected.

Also, here is my _reference.js file:

```
/// <autosync enabled="false" />
/// <reference path="require.js" data-main="main" />
```

Finally, if I don't use modules naming with define, intellisense don't work.